# How to formally prove: if d|(da+b), then d|b?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I formally prove that for the integers a, b, and d

If d|(da+b), then d|b. Would a direct proof be the best option? If I do a direct proof I seem to get stuck pretty quickly... in fact I don't even know how to start...

Assume d|(da+b)..?

This might look like a HW dump but I honestly just don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $d|da+b$ we can write $da+b=dk$. then $b=dk-da=d(k-a)$ and so $d|b$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $d$ does not divide $b$, so that $b=dq+r$  and EDIT r does not divide d. Then

$\frac {da+b}{b}=\frac{da+dq+r}{d}=\frac {d(a+q)+r}{d} $ , but r is not a factor of d.

Comment: $d\nmid b$ does _not_ imply $(r,d)=1$. $6\nmid 8$, but $8=6\cdot 1+2$ ($2<6$) and $(2,6)=2\neq 1$.

Comment: You're right, but we _can_ say that  d does not divide (r,d), which is what I will rewrite.

Comment: I just rewrote. Not a big deal, but I think this works.

Comment: No, $r$ need not be $<q$. $6\nmid 15$ and $15=6\cdot 2 + 3$ with $r=3>2=q$. It is enough to say: $\exists q\in\mathbb Z(b=dq+r, 0<r<d)$. Trivially $r$ can't divide $d$, since $d\cdot 0<r<d\cdot 1$ and $f(n)=dn$ is an increasing function. so no integer $n$ satisfies $f(n)=r$, since $f(0)<r<f(1)$.

Comment: I mixed up the condition in the division algorithm: a=bq+r , etc.